# Weird mesh tearing

Tags: mesh

An object I've made appears to have tearing on the corners. [video](https://youtu.be/m28StoNWPVk) All doubles are removed, it is scaled by 1 on all axes, It is auto smoothed but removing that does not fix it, turning double-sided on also does not fix it, the origin of the object is close. Mesh is triangulated, turning mesh into quads does not fix it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: could you please share the part of your object with the problem? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6307" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6307/) - hope this works

Comment: Your objects seem to be too small, scaling them up worked.

Comment: WhatAMesh is right, scale it up. Also, the rest of the lid topology is not very good, the long triangles tend to create artefacts, you should fix that, unless it doesn't create any visible problem when rendered?

Comment: @moonboots Will do!